# solving an equation with three unknowns (implicit family of curves)

Tags: python, math, sympy

I would like to get values of P, V and T that satisfy this equation, but it is taking a long time with `solve`. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
A = 1.855
B = 0.0426
C = 22570
a = 0.494
b = 0.00338
c = 2545
alfa = 0.000124
y = 0.006
R = 8.31446261815324
e = 2.718281
x = 2

from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import symbols

P, T, V = symbols('P T V')
eq = P - (R * T / V + (1 / V ** 2) * (R * T * (B + b / V) - (A + a / V - alfe * a / V ** 4) - (1 / T ** 2) * (
            C - c / V * (1 + x / V ** 2) * e ** (-x / V ** 2))))

print(solve([eq], [P, V, T], minimal=True, set=True))
```

Comment: In the supplied image of the equation, is there a superfluous minus sign in the square brackets?

Comment: You are writing `a ** a`, which means `a` to the power of `a`, but that doesn't seem to be present in the image.  Also note that sympy usually tries to find exact symbolic solutions, which doesn't work well with floats, which are imprecise by definition.  You might want to try numerical solving, e.g. by replacing `solve` by `nsolve` (and provide some initial values).

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do or what you hope to get as an answer because you have one equation and three unknowns. You can use e.g. `solve(eq, P)` to solve for `P` in terms of `V` and `T`. If that is not what you wanted then you will need to clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will edit the code. Let me try to explain it differently, I need to write a code that will search the parameters (P, V, T) so that the equation is solved.

Comment: Also note that is works quite fast (2 or 3 seconds) without `simplify`. Which tends to confirm the `float` hypothesis. Hard to simplify `x**2.5/x**1.5` to show a caricatural example, when you are not sure if 2.5-1.5 is exactly 1 or not.

Answer (score 1):

This equation doesn't have three roots. A polynomial in a single variable with degree 3 (i.e. `a*x**3 + b*x**2 +c*x + d`) would have three roots. An equation with three unknowns typically has an infinite number of solutions. Your equation is already 'solved'. Pick any nonzero values for T and V, plug them in, and you'll get a value for P. Choose different values for T and V, you'll still get a value for P. These are all solutions and you can always find more.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just need to find these variables (P, T, V), at least by brute force method, and then analyze the obtained data. I may have written the condition incorrectly, if so, I hope it's a little clearer now

Comment: @Di_maslo I don't know what you mean by 'now' since your question was last edited an hour ago. And I'm telling you that "find these variables" doesn't mean anything. You can find a bunch of values, e.g. `for T in T_values: for V in V_Values: P = ...` and that won't involve sympy at all. All nonzero values of T and V will have a solution, pick which ones you care about.

Comment: Is it possible to find float values with this search?

Comment: Sure, `for T in [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]: ...`

Answer (score 0):

I can see an error here:

```
a ** a / V ** 4
```

because:
[image]

and then you have 3 unkoknows in 1 equation, means that you don't have a closed form, so you have infinity raised 2 solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't really understand how I can fix the error in this case, can you advise me?

Comment: You'll need to add in another parameter for the alpha variable in the equation. So, defined a variable called `alpha` and switch `a ** a / V ** 4` to `alpha * a / V ** 4`. I'm not sure if this will help the equation to be solvable, but it will at least be consistent with the given equation.

Comment: I agree with Matt

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you want to do is to calculate contours for constant P for a given V and T -- your equation has these 3 variables (as others have pointed out) but you are interested in "solutions".

Solve your equation for `P` (since that's the linear variable). You now have a complicate expression for `P` in terms of `V` and `T`, `P = f(V,T)`. Let's calculate a curve for a given `P` value, say `P=1`. To do so we need to solve `P - f(V,T) = 0` which (in this case) is `1 - f(V,T) = 0`. Pick a value for `V`, say 1, and solve for the real root to get the corresponding value of `T`.

```py
from sympy import *
#...your code
# and then...
f = solve(eq, P)[0]
c1 = (1 - f).as_numer_denom()[0] # P = 1
>>> [i for i in real_roots(c1.subs(V,1)) if i][0].n(3)
13.7
```

That's 1 point on the `P=1` contour in the `(V ,T)` plane: (1,13.7). To get the next point at a different `V` in either directions use `nsolve` with that as the previous guess:

```py
>>> nsolve(c1.subs(V, 2), _).n(3)
10.9
```

This is called "continuation": using a previous vallue as the guess as to where the next solution "a little ways away" will be.

Rather than start at some arbitrary point in the middle I would decide on the `V` range of interest and start at the minimum value and increment and record the `(V, T)` points (for the desired `P`) as you go. Then plot them.

I let [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e1yjeejseb) do all the work by replacing `V` and `T` with `x` and `y` and selecting different values of `P` (0,5,10,15,20) to get these contours:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. My knowledge is not enough to understand the math of the .subs function. Can you please explain how it works or suggest literature where I could read it?

Comment: `(x + 1).subs(x,1) -> 2` - `subs(o, n)` replaces `o` in an expression with `n`. It's not math, per se, just an operation in SymPy.